# adjacency matrix in Java - edge overlapping

Tags: java, adjacency-matrix

I have a very simple question to ask.

I am using an adjacency matrix (2D array) in java to create a small graph with nodes and edges.

My problem is that when I instruct the program to iterate through the adjacency matrix,
using a simple nested loop, I experience the problem of edge overlapping. 
To be more specific, when matrix[i][j] is true and matrix[j][i] is true as well the app will try to draw 2 edges between nodes i and j which would be a waste and ugly-looking.

How can I overcome that problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't iterate across the entire matrix, you can use the upper triangular half (or the lower) and that will cover all of the entries you're interested in.

Assuming the matrix is diagonally symmetric, either half will suffice.  If it's not symmetric then you're using a directed graph (edges have arrows) and you would want to preserve those duplicate edges.

An easy way to iterate across a triangular half is this sort of nested loop:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
  for(j=i;j<m;j++){
   whatever(i,j);
  }
 }
```

Starting j=i means the columnar iteration starts from the diagonal and skips the duplicated portion.

Answer (score 2):

just go through half of the matrix (i.e. below the main diagonal)

do something like

```
for(i=1; i<= size; i++)
  for(j=i+1; j<= size; j++) 
     // draw
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is an undirected graph, in that case only the upper half (above the diagonal) of the matrix really contains any data.  If this is the case:

```
int[][] foo = //...

for(int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++){
    for(int j = i; j < foo[j].length; j++){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that using this iteration it's impossible to have duplicate edges as we only iterate through one half of the matrix.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your answers! you all suggested the same solution which simply WORKED! Thank you all for your time and efford writing that small snippet! I am gonna give the right answer "tick" to Karl just because I feel he was a bit more thorough with his explanation! My thanks to all of you again!